# Sum Number jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to sum like Ms Excel on html with jquery? And how about if there is a string inside like this `<td>USD 7.50</td>`, is it possible?

[jsfiddle link.](http://jsfiddle.net/1h4rr2s6/)

Sorry for my english btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make sum with a each of columns

```
var count=0;
$(".number").each(function(){
    count=count+parseInt($(this).html().replace("USD","").trim());
});
$(".footer-table tr td:last").html(count);
```

Comment: not working? http://jsfiddle.net/1h4rr2s6/2/

Comment: `parseInt` won't parse the USD text. Use `$(this).html().replace("USD, "")` instead

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/1h4rr2s6/3/ fixed :), sorry but your first example don't have USD

Answer (score 0):

If your column might have other text besides USD or possibly comas, you might consider a regex to replace everything that is not a number or a period.

**Note** that something like `G6 900.18`, would be seen as 6900.18 so be aware of that.

#### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1h4rr2s6/4/)

```
var count=0;
$(".number").each(function(){
    count = count + $(this).html().replace(/[^.\d]/g,'') * 1000;
});
$(".grand-total").html((count / 1000).toFixed(2));
```

Comment: i have no idea what this `/[^.\d]/g` mean, and why multiple 1000?

Comment: That is a regular expression that matches all characters that are not a digit or a period. Basically, it'll get rid of anything that is not 0-9 or a period which would be more useful if for example, you may sometimes show the amounts in a different currency. The multiplying by 1000 then dividing by 1000 is to avoid unexpected behaviour that can occur when doing math with floats in `javascript` see [Is floating point math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) for more info. If you know you'll never have decimal numbers, you wont need that.